# Is it possible to have a consistent setup.py file that reflects local changes to dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, package

Let's say I have two distinct Python projects, `libr` (a library) and `proj` (a project that depends on `libr`).

If I set up a private package index and list `libr` as a dependency in `setup.py`, I can tell `pip` to use it using `--index-url`... but if I want to test out how a change in `libr` affects `proj`, I need to upload the new version to the private index and reinstall.

If I instead tell `pip` to look for `libr` in my local filesystem using `--editable`, I will be able to test out the code without uploading, but my `setup.py` will be polluted with paths instead of package names.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: If your `libr` is a pure python library, you can just add that path to your `PYTHONPATH` instead of installing it. Isn't it convenient enough?

Comment: I don't understand why you will have paths in `setup.py` and not just package names.

Comment: Well, if `install_requires` contains `'libr'`, `$ pip install -e .` will complain `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libr (from versions: )`